# Is it possible to stay full time at a temple/religious location for an year or so?

Tags: temple, life

Since over a year I've this disconnect with everything around me, people and work and everything else and now, sometimes have suicidal thoughts.

I wish to stay away from all this and find a meaning to life. I don't have much money with me.

I want to stay at a temple or some similar institution for some time, maybe a year or two, maybe longer. Is there any such institution where I can stay.

**What policy does ISKON follow?** I am willing to do work or volunteer for their activities etc but I can't spend much money. Please suggest if I should post this to some other site if Hinduism.SE isn't appropriate.

I'm a 25 year old boy in India.

Comment: I think you are looking for spiritual guidance. Then you need guru. Search for a good ashram. You can also be like _sevak_ who keep the temples clean.

Comment: I agree. Any suggestions? I tried to google but they all seem to make a business out of it.

Comment: I don't think this is a valid question for the site. I'll keep it open for now, will raise a question on meta and then decide to close your question.

Comment: fist of all convert the suicidal thoughts to vairagya (thougts of being unattached to holy world) and then continue with vairagya to find a right guide or guru then serve him till end of you reach your goal so that even death can't stop you. also you can find the right place in rishikesh at divine life society math they will help and guide you (this is one of many which I know you can prefer any of them as you like and as your fate decides)

Comment: Who deleted my answer? At least convert it to comment.

Comment: Nobody should delete answers unless severely downvoted. If someone has privileges to delete, they should not be misused. **If you don't like it, it doesn't mean you should delete it,** just downvote it and see if the community thinks the same. On stackexchange, bad answers sink to the bottom, not disappear. Without down votes, it should not even be possible to delete. Also, just one person should not even be able to delete anything, community should decide.

Comment: @ShreemayPanhalkar your post was deleted on basis of this [meta discussion](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/296/93). Please add your inputs there if you think deleting your post was not a good idea.

Comment: @ShreemayPanhalkar If you see, I've commented on your post as well, I think you have missed the notification or you ignored my comment which explains why I deleted your answer. Secondly, I cannot convert your answer into a comment because it is big.

Comment: @user714 Hello and welcome to Hinduism.SE. Community makes rules over here, and according [to this meta post](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/296/93) your question is somewhat off-topic for the site, it will be nice if you edit out your personal issues from the question and keep it a simple one else we have to close it unfortunately. Also, moderators keeps cleaning the site, so we can surely delete the posts which are not suitable for the site. If you have any questions over the actions taken, [feel free to complain on meta](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions).

Comment: Ok I think you didn't made any necessary changes to the post so I will close your question as of now else it will attract low quality answers. Flag me if you make any changes so that I can reopen your post. For more information on this refer [this](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/299/) and [this](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/296/) post on meta

Comment: Dear User214 - Hope you are doing well. Did you find an answer to your question? Please visit your local Ramakrishna Mission or Sringeri and seek the guidance of the gurus there. You can even write a letter to Sringeri jagadguru in detail or even just pray mentally. The gurus will give you answers. Please be well. It is not at all wise to commit suicide as it will have severe long term ramifications on your soul. Please reply to this comment if you are doing reasonably well. I am sorry I saw your post only now.